# Change route path name with a variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I have a products index which has a list of categories. I used named scopes in my products model for each category, with each category in the view having a link routing users to a products index filtered accordingly. I have a list of routes for each scope. In the view, I want to replace the route path dynamically with a variable such as VAR_products_path. What's the proper syntax for it?

## Products index

```
- @categories.each do |cat|
- @product = Product.where("category_id = ?", cat.id)
= link_to "#{cat.category_name}", cat.category_name_products_path# architecture_products_path or arts_products_path
```

## Products controller

```
def architecture
params[:category]
@categories = Category.all
@products = Product.architecture
render action: :index
end
```

## Routes file

```
resources :products do
collection do
get :architecture 
get :arts
get :business
...
```

## Product model

```
scope :architecture, -> { where(category_id: 1) }
scope :arts -> { where(category_id: 2) }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
= link_to cat.category_name, public_send("#{cat.category_name}_products_path")
```

Although I'd consider changing your routes to take the category name as an argument, for example `/products/{category}` so you could use it more nicely `products_path(cat.category_name)`.